# Add indendation to lines after a number

Tags: indentation, paragraphs

1. The English Wikipedia was the first Wikipedia edition and has remained the 
   largest. It has pioneered many ideas as conventions, policies or features which were later adopted by Wikipedia editions in some of the other languages.
2. Although the English Wikipedia stores images and audio files, as well as text 
   files,many of the images have been moved to Wikimedia Commons with the same 
   name, as passed-through files

I need to indent paragraphs as shown above after adding numbers as points in latex. What are the scripts required to do so??

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please post a minimal example of what you've got so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\noindent
Some text before ...
\begin{enumerate}
\item
The English Wikipedia was the first Wikipedia edition and has remained the largest. It has 
pioneered many ideas as conventions, policies or features which were later adopted by 
Wikipedia editions in some of the other languages.
\item
Although the English Wikipedia stores images and audio files, as well as text files,many 
of the images have been moved to Wikimedia Commons with the same name, as passed-through 
files
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]